# Why x% is not a valid value of attribute 'width' in Visual Studio?

Tags: html, visual-studio-2017, width

[image: Visual Studio table element's width attribute]

I'm trying to create a scale-able table so I put it value in %. The website works just fine but why Visual Studio counts it as invalid?

Comment: Is it configured to follow HTML5 standard? %-widths are not valid for it many elements (like tables), so you should be using CSS.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It might be using a set of code analysis rules that deal with best practices. According to [the MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table), that `width` attribute has been deprecated and should not be used:

> Do not use this attribute, as it has been deprecated. The rules should be defined and styled using CSS.

As mentioned, you should style your table using CSS. Apply a class to the table element and define the style as such:

**HTML**

```
<table class="my-table"></table>
```

**CSS**

```
.my-table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I guess the flip side is figuring out at what point CSS `width` became supported, b/c browsers down to Mosaic and back up to current Chrome Canary probably do `width="100%"` just fine. (That said, it looks like, unless you're supporting IE 3, [you should be fine with CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#Browser_compatibility).)